# CreateJS filter performance

Tags: javascript, filter, easeljs, createjs

I have been developing a game using CreateJS and noticed significant performance drop when any filter is applied to image. I created this small test case to showcase the problem:

```
var isInitialized = false;

function start(preload) {

    egg = preload.getResult("Kiausinis");

    center = new Vector(stage.canvas.width/2,stage.canvas.height/2);

    eggImg = new createjs.Bitmap(egg);
    stage.addChild(eggImg);
    eggImg.x = center.x-300;
    eggImg.y = center.y;
    centerOrigin(eggImg);
    eggImg.on("click",applyFilters);

    eggImg2 = new createjs.Bitmap(egg);
    stage.addChild(eggImg2);
    eggImg2.x = center.x;
    eggImg2.y = center.y;
    centerOrigin(eggImg2);

    eggImg3 = new createjs.Bitmap(egg);
    stage.addChild(eggImg3);
    eggImg3.x = center.x+300;
    eggImg3.y = center.y;
    centerOrigin(eggImg3);

    fpsLabel = new createjs.Text("fps:","150px Verdana","black");
    fpsLabel.lineWidth = 200;
    fpsLabel.textAlign = "center";
    fpsLabel.x = center.x;
    fpsLabel.y = center.y;
    stage.addChild(fpsLabel);

    isInitialized = true;

}

function update(){

    if(!isInitialized) return;

    fpsLabel.text= "fps: " + Math.round(createjs.Ticker.getMeasuredFPS(3));
    stage.update();

}

function centerOrigin(img){

    img.regX = img.getBounds().width/2;
    img.regY = img.getBounds().height/2;

}

function applyFilters(){

    changeImgColor(eggImg,1,0.8,0.7,1);
    changeImgColor(eggImg2,1,0.8,0.7,1);
    changeImgColor(eggImg3,1,0.8,0.7,1);

}

function changeImgColor(img, r, g, b, a){

    img.filters = [

        new createjs.ColorFilter(r, g, b, a)

    ];

    img.cache(0,0,img.getBounds().width,img.getBounds().height);
    img.updateCache();

}
```

code shows a primitive set up. Add three images to stage and when one of them is clicked apply color filter to all of them. Before applying filter I get arround 200fps on desktop and mobile. After the filter is applied it instantly drops to around 5fps on mobile. Even though framerate drops to 5fps the counter still shows 200fps (you can tell that framerate dropped because fps counter refreshes very slowly now).

A live demo can be seen here: http://spaceout.bugs3.com/performanceTest/

What is happening here? Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone else encountered similar problems?

Thank you.

Comment: What does applyFilters do? if it's some heavy image processing you can expect that to have a pretty big impact.

Comment: You can see the code, it applies filter and caches the image. This is done for a single frame so for my understanding it cant have that much of an effect on performance.

Comment: When profiling you can see the filter call taking a lot of time, and doing multiple getImageData calls. Check out this screenshot from Chrome http://imgur.com/8BqFtQR

Comment: you should be able to connect Chrome to the mobile device, using chrome://inspect and do some profiling to see what exactly takes so long to repaint. :)

Comment: This profiling tool seems like a black magic to me. Could you give me more insight into what is happening? Also I still don't seem to understand the problem with the filter call. It is called only once after click so what importance should it have on redrawing every frame?

Comment: Well, on  my desktop after every click it took about 200ms to redraw everything. I'm not sure how the library behaves on mobile devices (maybe there's some constant redrawing taking place). The picture I linked shows the programs' stacktrace and how long every method call took. You can find more about the profiler in the chrome dev tools here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

Comment: As a note. I just tried running your example on my tablet and i got the same results i got on my desktop. Starts @ 200 fps. If i click the 1st egg it locks up for a little while (fps of 3 to 7) then it goes back to 200. It looks like the filters from that library are just highly inneficient. :(

Comment: Do I understand this correctly the framerate drops and then returns to 200 again? Because for me it drops and never gets back.

Comment: Creating & applying filters is a fairly expensive operation, so doing it once, up-front, is the best approach. If you need to transition filters, then using multiple instances and cross-fading is usually a good way to achieve that effect. One quick note that updateCache() is not necessary – it is used to draw the contents into the existing cache, which you don't need to do here.

Comment: So isn't that what I'm doing? applying filter only once? Why do I see the performance decrease all the time after applying the filter?